# How do I format my text in Google Script, for it to show when I send an email?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, formatting

I have been trying to edit a script that I have to bold certain text. This script pulls information from a Google Form Spreadsheet and returns an email that looks like this:

---

Teacher Engagement:
At initial observation, the teacher is appropriately engaged (Direct Instruction, Modeling, Constructing Knowledge, Guided/Independent Practice, etc.)

Technology Integration:
No evidence of technology use or integration

---

I would like for the headers "Teacher Engagement:" & "Technology Integration" to be Bold and maybe underlined.How can I implement HTML into my code?

My code is:

```
function sendEmail() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

var userEmail = sheet.getRange(row,   
  getColIndexByName("Username")).getValue();

var body = "Below are the results of a recent Walkthrough: ";

 body += "\n\nTeacher Engagement: \n" + sheet.getRange(row,     
  getColIndexByName("Teacher Engagement")).getValue();

 body += "\n\nTechnology Integration: \n" + sheet.getRange(row,     
  getColIndexByName("Technology Integration")).getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"Classroom Walkthrough"});
}
```

Comment: see the official docs where it has a sample html email sent. try to convert the current string to html also as its currently not in that format. for example replace the "\n" with html paragraphs or just <br> to keep it simple. give it a try first and update us wirh your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only viable solution to format an E-mail with the MailApp is to use the HTMLbody option and to write your texte as HTML.

example :

```
function sendEmail() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

var userEmail = sheet.getRange(row,   
getColIndexByName("Username")).getValue();

var body = "<HTML><BODY>"
+"Below are the results of a recent Walkthrough: "
+"<P>Teacher Engagement: <BR>" 
+sheet.getRange(row,getColIndexByName("Teacher Engagement")).getValue()
+"</P>"
+"<P>Technology Integration: <BR>" 
+sheet.getRange(row,getColIndexByName("Technology Integration")).getValue()
+"</P></BODY></HTML>";

MailApp.sendEmail({
to:userEmail,
subject:subject,
htmlBody:body,
name:"Classroom Walkthrough"
});
}
```

result :

```
Below are the results of a recent Walkthrough: 

Teacher Engagement: 
stuff

Technology Integration: 
other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Orange Bender! Your code worked, I just had to add <b> </b> to the areas I wanted to bold. The email ended up looking great and way easier to read. Thanks again.