# How do I send Google App Script email using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have been trying to learn how to send script emails using html but I have a challenge with dynamic data and I need help.

I would like to check a google sheet for projects that ended and send this as a table via email script.

The sheet looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code that reads the spreadsheet:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Projects"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:O20");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[11];
    var recipient = rowData[8];
    var end_date = rowData[2];
    var message1 = 'Kindly note that the project'
    var message2 = 'was scheduled to end on' + ' ' + end_date +'. Please confirm the end date and if it needs to be readjusted. If the project is on course please fill the project end survey '
    var message3 = 'Thanks'
    var pro_name = rowData[4];
    var pro_code = rowData[5];
    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + pro_name + ' '  + message2 + '.\n\n'   + message3;
    var subject = 'Project End: ' + pro_name;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

I have come up with basic HTML file, and I am lost on how to link both and only send emails to a person whose project ended.

```
<div dir="ltr">Hi,
    <div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:none">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="153">
                    <col width="125">
                        <col width="141">
                            <col width="100">
                                <col width="375">
                                    <col width="119">
                                        <col width="132">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height:21px">
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Project_State</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Start_Date</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">End_Date</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Project_ID</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Project_Name</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Project_Code</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Type</td>
                </tr>
                <? for(var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) { ?>
                    <tr style="height:29px">
                        <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= proData[i].project_name ?></td>
                        <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= proData[i].project_code ?></td>
                        <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">1<?= proData[i].end_date ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <? } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Suggestion: Start by keeping the html simple and then progressively you can get more complex.

Comment: Use the version of `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{htmlBody:yourhtml});`

Comment: A lot of people use templated html:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send HTML with Apps Script using the `MailApp` class you should use the `options` object to pass the advanced parameter [`htmlBody`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#advanced-parameters_1)

This options object could include all the email message parameters or only the HTML for the message body.

An example:

```js
function sendHtml() {
  // Send HTML content in email.

  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('your-html-file').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test Email markup - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a HTML in a email message to be sent by using Google Apps Script you should use the `options` object.

This options object could include all the email message parameters or only the HTML for the message body.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Related

- [How do I format my text in Google Script, for it to show when I send an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31663006/1595451)
- [How to include inline images in email using MailApp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36178369/1595451)
- [How do I send an email in google apps script with basic text formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54586334/1595451)